# Converting Betwixt (Between) String to Integer Datatype

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, scipy, astronomy

I am trying to convert the distance of Jupiter which is in AU (Astronomical Unit) to Lightyears, I am using preexisting modules which means you have no preference over the data types and i am having the following error.

I am using the modules Skyfield (Skyfield.api to be specific) and Scipy
My code:

```
from scipy import constants
from skyfield.api import load
planets = load('de421.bsp')
earth, jupiter = planets['earth'], planets['JUPITER BARYCENTER']
ts = load.timescale()
t = ts.now()
astrometric = earth.at(t).observe(jupiter)
radec=astrometric.radec()

# int(constants.astronomical_unit / constants.light_year ) * int(str(radec[2])

# Since the above line is not working i tried this:

int(constants.astronomical_unit / constants.light_year ) * int(str(radec[2]).replace("au", "").strip())
```

Error:

int(constants.light_year / constants.astronomical_unit) * int(str(radec[2]).replace("au", ""))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4.63954'

I at first thought the whitespace might be the reason but even when i applied the `strip()` function the error persists still

my Python version is `Python 3.9.12`

Comment: use `strip()` to remove whitespaces

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives the same error

Comment: then there may be a whitespace inside the numeric value string still, try `split()`

Comment: Thanks, but the same error persists

Comment: That doesn't look much like a number you'd want to round down to an integer. Are you sure you don't want `float()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `int(radec[2].au)` instead of  `int(str(radec[2]))` so it becomes:

```
int(constants.light_year / constants.astronomical_unit) * int(radec[2].au))
```

If you print it you get `252964`.

**Note:**
You should consider making all the calculations on floats and at the end, convert the answer to int:

```
print(int(float(constants.light_year / constants.astronomical_unit) * float(radec[2].au)))
```

Which gives `293505`.

Comment: Sorry, it's constants.astronomical_unit / constants.light_year

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string value of radec[2] to a float before converting it to an integer

```
int(constants.light_year / constants.astronomical_unit) * 
int(float(str(radec[2]).replace("au", "").strip()))
```

Comment: I guess if you calculate something about lightyears and astronomic units (au) you want to be precise, so maybe just use float instead of cast it to int

Comment: Thanks, Juancito Surinam

Comment: Sorry, it's constants.astronomical_unit / constants.light_year